# How to add PHP and SQL to stylesheet

Tags: php, css

I have a form that allows users to change the styling of the site they're on. I tried saving my stylesheet as a PHP file, but now the styles aren't showing up, event though I changed the stylesheet link to href="styles.php". How can I get the PHP stylesheet to affect my pages? Here is the stylesheet code:

```
<?php include("session_start.php")?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM styles WHERE user_name='$user_name'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

?>

<?php
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

body {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background-color: <?php echo $column['background_color'] ?>;
color: <?php echo $column['text_color'] ?>;
font-size: <?php echo $column['body_size'] ?>; 
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
color: <?php echo $column['header_color'] ?>; 
}

h1 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h1_size'] ?>; 
}

h2 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h2_size'] ?>; 
}

h3 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h3_size'] ?>; 
}

h4 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h4_size'] ?>; 
}

h5 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h5_size'] ?>; 
}

h6 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h6_size'] ?>; 
}

.registration-form {
max-width: 300px;
margin: 100px auto;
}

.align-right {
text-align: right;
}

#post_content {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}

.view-post-content {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.category {
font-weight: bold;
}

hr {
border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

a:hover {
color: purple;
}

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you set `$user_name`?

Comment: Can your query really return multiple rows? If it does, you'll get multiple styles for the same elements. If not, why do you have a `while` loop to process the results?

Comment: @Barmar $user_name is set in the session. As far as the while loop, I'm only using that because that's how I learned how to return data.

Comment: Try understanding *why* you do things, instead of just blindly copying them. You use a loop if you need to do something repetitively. If there's no repetition, you don't need a loop. Programming is not copy-paste.

Comment: If `$user_name` is set correctly, I think this should work. Do you see the file being loaded in Developer Tools?

Comment: please add "<style type="text/css">"

Comment: if you are create inline css then you have to add this <style type="text/css"> and check inspect element your changes are apear or not.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, it turns out $user_name wasn't set correctly. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

body {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background-color: <?php echo $column['background_color'] ?>;
color: <?php echo $column['text_color'] ?>;
font-size: <?php echo $column['body_size'] ?>; 
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
color: <?php echo $column['header_color'] ?>; 
}

h1 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h1_size'] ?>; 
}

h2 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h2_size'] ?>; 
}

h3 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h3_size'] ?>; 
}

h4 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h4_size'] ?>; 
}

h5 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h5_size'] ?>; 
}

h6 {
font-size: <?php echo $column['h6_size'] ?>; 
}

.registration-form {
max-width: 300px;
margin: 100px auto;
}

.align-right {
text-align: right;
}

#post_content {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}

.view-post-content {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.category {
font-weight: bold;
}

hr {
border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

a:hover {
color: purple;
}

<?php
} ?>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a php file and 
add this code to your file simple => style.php
    header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
and add your styles and add file to your page style